How to import the same redis connection (just switching the database) in different modules of nestjs?
I am trying to implement a @nestjs/typeorm like module in nestjs for redis (for learning and experimenting). I have created a module which connects to a redis instance.
Using CacheModule.forRoot(options) I am able to connect successfully but I cannot figure out how to implement forFeature for this module. I want to import this module in another modules like: CacheModule.forFeature(databaseNumber: number). I need the module importing this to use only the database which it is concerned with but the question is How do I get the client instance already initialized by forRoot and provide the instance returned when I select a database?
import { DynamicModule, Global, Module, Provider } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CacheService } from './cache.service';
import { RedisClientOptions } from 'redis';

@Module({})
export class CacheModule {
    static forRoot(options: RedisClientOptions): DynamicModule {
        const dataSourceProvider: Provider = {
            provide: 'REDIS_CLIENT',
            useFactory: async () => {
                return await createClient(this.options).connect();
            },
        };

        return {
            module: CacheModule,
            imports: [],
            providers: [dataSourceProvider, CacheService],
            exports: [CacheService],
        };
    }
}

